# ubuntu 14.04 LTS bluetooth mouse connects but doesn't move the pointer or is not working

Tags: 14.04, wireless, mouse, bluetooth, lts

As you can see below, my Bluetooth mouse is connected, but it doesn't move the pointer and all the mouse buttons doesn't work too. I believe it might need some settings to be done, but I don't know how. I am used to plug and play, not so much in connect wirelessly through Bluetooth and play. The Bluetooth device works on windows. I wish for it to work on my Ubuntu 14.04 L.T.S. I have done the common things, which has done wonders for me.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

updated from the update button too

alas... I am force to come here and see if anyone has a solution for me...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post the output of `xinput`. Did you try to [install additional drivers](/q/47506/175814)?

Comment: added xinput output

Comment: Thanks. Xorg recognises your Bluetooth mouse (ID 14 currently). Maybe it's disabled for some reason. Can you please post the output of `xinput --list-props 'Bluetooth Mouse'`. It would be better to add program output listings like this as text and use [code formatting](/editing-help#code) (the `<$>` button in the editor toolbar).